# Advice to learn about MEAP concepts

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, mobile, mobile-application

I need some help in understanding MEAP concepts. Googling it, I can get some stuff like enterprise mobile apps, etc.

I don't need theory, I need a working example or an IDE to develop mobile apps for cross platforms. So is there any good platform that helps in achieving it?

I am now learning to work in Phonegap apps. It is fine but I'm not aware of any other such things to develop cross platform apps for mobile.

Any ideas on Convertigo, and other such platforms are also welcome.

Comment: a downvote ?? kind sir,May i know where im unclear ?

Comment: The downvotes may be because the question is too vague and discursive. When you get a moment, have a read of the FAQ here - we like specific (and ideally code-based) questions that have a definitive answer. Clear, correctly-spelled questions that have clearly involved effort are appreciated too - see my edit.

Comment: Voting to close. Please don't rollback good edits - you'll get flagged if you do.

Comment: I'm not sure why the downvote was cast, but I can guess. Your first line "I can get blah blah"... really? Then you go and ask randomly for an example, there is no question in your 'question', you use too many ! and ? (one 1 enough per sentence). It's just not very usefull... BUt that's just guessing :)

Comment: so..u declare this question is not useful to anyone uh ?? good..I ve jus asked some help on a topic and you mean to close the question...??

Comment: Read this please: http://stackoverflow.com/faq. A better approach would be to cite a specific problem you are facing with this topic, what you have tried, and what can be done to solve it. At the moment, a whole book would answer your question `:)`.

Comment: @Nanne:OK guys.I didnt get help on this question.but i surely did some knowledge on "HOW TO ASK A QUESTION". Thanks 4 dat anyways.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hey Some good starting practical examples for Cross Platform Mobile Application Platforms are:

1. [Icenium](http://app.icenium.com) from Telerik : This tool helps you to build HTML5 apps using jQuery Mobile/KendoUI framework and easily test the app on its online emulators or on your device by creating a temporary build.

IMP: You are required to do coding in this platform and hence it is more flexible.

1. [Tiggzi](http://tiggzi.com/home) : Build real HTML5, jQuery Mobile mobile apps and hybrid apps for Android, iOS and Windows Phone (with Apache Cordova/PhoneGap). As the builder is running in the cloud, there is nothing to install or download so it’s very easy to build your app.

IMP: You can use its drag n drop feature to create rapid prototypes.

MEAP - Mobile Enterprise Application Platforms are end to end solutions that also provide app management, device management features. Some of the top MEAPs are:

Kony
IBM Worklight
SAP Unqired Platform
Antenna AmpChroma

All of these come as an Eclipse Plugin but have a lot of inbuilt tools to build and manage mobile applications.

Out of these only IBM Worklight has a trial version:
https://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/iwm/web/signup.do?source=swg-worklight&S_TACT=109KA6TW&S_CMP=web_ibm_ws_mobile_bd_worklight

Comment: Now thats an perfect answer i was looking for..